# How to parse date in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a string like Oct 26, 2017 I want to convert to a date.

I've tried

```
select PARSE_DATE('%m %d, %Y',  my_date)
from my_table
```

But I get

```
Failed to parse input string "Oct 26, 2017"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date for the formatting elements.

So you probably need '%b %d, %Y'. That is assuming your days are always 2 numbers.